# When do we need to integrate WSO2 API Manager with WSO2 G-registry?

Tags: wso2, integration, wso2-api-manager, wso2-governance-registry

I have done through the WSO2 Documentation and Webinar on integrating WSO2 API Manager with WSo2 G-registry. But still I'm not clear about during which Business scenario or to solve which business problem we need to integrate these two products?

I kindly request you to please give me your valuable ideas.

Comment: Please go through this webinar to have better understanding on G-reg integration with APIM http://wso2.com/library/webinars/2015/12/wso2-governance-registry-and-wso2-api-manager-integration/

Comment: I have gone through the above webinar hence posted the question above. Kindly specify the scenarios(just 2 or 3 Bullet points) during which we Integrate these products

Answer (score 2):

Basically you will need to go for a solution with an integration of APIM and GREG to cater below requirements.

1. Assume that there are different types of assets in your organization such as WSDLs, services, endpoints, APIs, etc which you want to govern from a central point. Also you have the requirement to allow those to be explored in a central store. This can be achieved from GREG + APIM integration where you can use the central Publisher to govern all the assets and use its store to explore all the artifacts. Same time all the APIM capabilities will be there to expose managed APIs.
2. Assume that you have multiple APIM environments such as DEV, QA, PROD, etc. You want to manage the API in all the environments from a single publisher. It can be achieved from this solution where you can define multiple endpoints to the same API asset and push them to the relevant environment using lefecycle executors.